# Power BI Publish Report Fails with 400 Bad request (using Azure Blob Storage)

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to publish a Power BI report using Power BI REST APIS but i get a RequestedFileIsEncryptedOrCorrupted error.
Documentation for the Power BI request can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/postimportingroup.

Here are the steps I am following

1. Create a temporary Blob Location

Request

```
POST /v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/imports/createTemporaryUploadLocation HTTP/1.1
Host: api.powerbi.com
Authorization: Bearer {token}
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: api.powerbi.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

which returns the following data

```
{
  "@odata.context": "",
  "url": "",
  "expirationTime": ""
}
```

2. Push file to temp blob location

then using the url I send the following request

```
PUT {url from step 1} HTTP/1.1
Host: wabieus2bppbiv2.blob.core.windows.net
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: wabieus2bppbiv2.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 2057012
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache


Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="{local pbix file path here}
```

This request responds with a 201 created

Then I send the publish report call

```
POST /v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/imports?datasetDisplayName={name}&amp; nameConflict=CreateOrOverwrite&amp; skipReport=False HTTP/1.1
Host: api.powerbi.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
cache-control: no-cache

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUrl"

{url from step 1}
```

I get a 400 Bad Request Error with the following data

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestedFileIsEncryptedOrCorrupted",
    "pbi.error": {
      "code": "RequestedFileIsEncryptedOrCorrupted",
      "parameters": {},
      "details": [],
      "exceptionCulprit": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on what is causing this issue?